# Generating release notes in Rep. in GIT

Tags: git, repository, release

I am having a repository in which I would like to mention in it, in every changes, release notes and log file.

How to generate those files?

Comment: Do you want something to *generate* log files and release notes, or are you asking how to add them to git. Why does this have a C++ tag?

Comment: @doctorlove to answer you: I would like to generate log file/release notes.

Comment: @doctorlove C++ tag: because my project is in c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to create build notes you can use

```
git log LAST_TAG..THIS_TAG
```

If your commits have something like JiraID or whatever you can do

```
git log --grep JiraID LAST_TAG..THIS_TAG
```

and later parse it in whatever way.

Comment: then, using the GIT commands is the best way to deal with all that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple bash script to generate ReleaseNotes.txt. 
Just copy paste the script to the checkout dir of your code and run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will generate the release notes from the commits
#It will discard prints oF automatic Merges and Pull Requests commits. 
#It will show all the Commits date wise and sorted

DATE=
git log --pretty=format:"%ad || %h || %s || Author:%an " --date=short | sort -r | while read line
do
temp=`echo $line | egrep -v '(Automatic merge from|Merge pull request|Merge conflict from|Resolve Conflict From)'`
if [ "$temp" = "" ]
then
    continue
else
    NEWDATE=`echo $temp |  awk  '{print $1}'`
    if [ "$NEWDATE" = "$DATE" ]
    then
        echo $temp | awk '{$1="";$2="";print}' >> releaseNotes.txt
    else
        echo >> releaseNotes.txt
        DATE=$NEWDATE
        echo `date --date=$DATE +%d-%B-%Y` >> releaseNotes.txt
        echo $temp | awk '{$1="";$2="";print}' >> releaseNotes.txt
    fi
fi
done
```